# Python CFFI convert structure to dictionary

Tags: python, python-cffi

There is a way to initialize structure with dictionary:

```
fooData= {'y': 1, 'x': 2}
fooStruct = ffi.new("foo_t*", fooData)
fooBuffer = ffi.buffer(fooStruct)
```

Is there some ready function to do the conversion?

```
fooStruct = ffi.new("foo_t*")
(ffi.buffer(fooStruct))[:] = fooBuffer
fooData= convert_to_python( fooStruct[0] )
```

Do I have to use ffi.typeof("foo_t").fields by myself?

I come up with this code so far:

```
def __convert_struct_field( s, fields ):
    for field,fieldtype in fields:
        if fieldtype.type.kind == 'primitive':
            yield (field,getattr( s, field ))
        else:
            yield (field, convert_to_python( getattr( s, field ) ))

def convert_to_python(s):
    type=ffi.typeof(s)
    if type.kind == 'struct':
        return dict(__convert_struct_field( s, type.fields ) )
    elif type.kind == 'array':
        if type.item.kind == 'primitive':
            return [ s[i] for i in range(type.length) ]
        else:
            return [ convert_to_python(s[i]) for i in range(type.length) ]
    elif type.kind == 'primitive':
        return int(s)
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: There is no built-in way, no.  Usually it's not needed: just use the cdata object directly, without converting it to dictionaries and lists first.

Comment: @ArminRigo I need to convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Arpegius' solution works fine for me, and is quite elegant. I implemented a solution based on Selso's suggestion to use inspect. dir() can substitute inspect.

```py
from inspect import getmembers
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
from pprint import pprint

def cdata_dict(cd):
    if isinstance(cd, ffi.CData):
        try:
            return ffi.string(cd)
        except TypeError:
            try:
                return [cdata_dict(x) for x in cd]
            except TypeError:
                return {k: cdata_dict(v) for k, v in getmembers(cd)}
    else:
        return cd

foo = ffi.new("""
struct Foo {
    char name[6];
    struct {
        int a, b[3];
    } item;
} *""",{
    'name': b"Foo",
    'item': {'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
})
pprint(cdata_dict(foo))
```

Output:

```py
{'item': {'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2, 3]}, 'name': b'Foo'}
```

Comment: Wow I am glad that after six years some one is still itrested in this question.  Unfortunatly,  for perfomance reasons, we changed to PyPy and used only cffi structures and others serialization methods.

Answer (score 1):

This code infortunately does not work for me, as some struct members are "pointer" types, it leads to storing "none" in the dict.

I am a Python noob, but maybe the inspect module would be another starting point, and a shorter way to print "simple" data. Then we would iterate over the result in order to unroll data structure.

For example with the following example :

```
struct foo {
int a;
char b[10];
};
```

Using inspect.getmembers( obj ) I have the following result :

```
[('a', 10), ('b', <cdata 'char[10]' 0x7f0be10e2824>)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

Even if there was a built-in way in CFFI, it would not be what you need here.  Indeed, you can say `ffi.new("foo_t*", {'p': p1})` where `p1` is another cdata, but you cannot recursively pass a dictionary containing more dictionaries.  The same would be true in the opposite direction: you would get a dictionary that maps field names to "values", but the values themselves would be more cdata objects anyway, and not recursively more dictionaries.

Comment: Wow I did not known, even do not test it. Hopefully there was no structures with structure fields, passing to C. Anyway I leave this question open, maybe some one make that functionality in next version of cffi.